# Why do newlines effect eval return?

Tags: javascript, eval

I was fixing a bug this morning and came across this strange quirk in `eval`.

If you try to evaluate:
`var e = "true true"; console.log(eval(e));`.

The console throws an exception, but if you add a line break between the two conditions:
`var e = "true\n true"; console.log(eval(e));`

The console returns true.

I know `eval` is *evil* and I've solved the problem by stripping out the newlines, but I was wondering why this difference occurs. I had a quick Google for newlines and eval but came up with nothing.

Comment: Because `true true` is an invalid Javascript expression, but `true\ntrue` is parsed as two separate statements…

Comment: You'd get the same result if you didn't involve `eval`.